# Add intermediate values to a list using the LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq :

`listA` contains `Id`, `Date` `ValueId`, and `Value`

```
List<int> valueIds=new List<int>();
//valueIds contains the intermediate values of value ids

from x by listA
 group x by new {Id=x.Id, Date=x.date}
  into g
 let sum= g.Sum(x=>!valueIds.Contains(x.ValueId):x.Value:0)
//I don't want to sum it if the valueIds are already added for sum
 select {
        Id =x.Id
        Value=sum
        }
```

How do I add the intermediate values to the list `valueIds` so that I could only `sum` for the values that are not already aggregated?

Any help is much appreciated. 
Sorry, if the question sounds unclear, I was trying to simplify it as much as possible.

Thanks.

What I want is:

E.g. If listA contains the list of students and their details of class attendance on each subject. Generally each subject is taught 1 hour which is counted as `one class attendance`. When a student attends two subjects (SubA and SubB) half an hour each `on the same day`, the class attendance count should still be `1`. 
So, when I group by student, date and subject, I don't want to distribute attendance `one` to both (SubA and SubB) but to only SubA (first occurrence). 
This somewhat describes my scenario, but please do not compare this with real world scenario :)

## Or

If I have a following foreach statement:

```
 List<int> valueIds=new List<int>();
 List<SomeClass> listB=new List<SomeClass>();

foreach (var x by listA.GroupBy(new {Id=x.Id, Date=x.date}))
 {
    var sum= g.Sum(x=>!valueIds.Contains(x.ValueId):x.Value:0)
    valueIds.Add(x.ValueId)
    listB.Add(new SomeClass{Id=x.Id, Value=sum)});
 }
```

Is this possible to do this in a single `linq` statement instead of foreach?

Comment: Your LINQ describes not that much about what you have and what you want. Can you describe this in words? What do you want to achieve? How should the result look like?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. How are you expecting the intermediate values in `valueIds` to be populated?

Comment: @Enigmativity exactly. I wanted to know if it's possible at all. Like using `aggregate` function sort of.

Comment: @ZammyPage - What do you mean "exactly"? Are you saying **you're** as confused as me?

Comment: I meant exactly how do I populate the intermediate values in `valuesIds` buddy?